# Django update form fields return as blank

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have the following view

```
class ProductUpdateView(BaseProductUpdateView):
    form_class = ProductForm
    slug_field = "id"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.hotel = form.cleaned_data["hotel"]
        form.instance.parent = form.cleaned_data["parent"]
        return super(ProductUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

and following form:

```
class ProductForm(BaseProductForm):
    hotel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Hotel.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput)
    parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=forms.TextInput, required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ('slug', 'parent', 'hotel', 'status', 'score', 'product_class',
                   'recommended_products', 'related_products',
                   'product_options', 'attributes', 'categories')
```

When I save the form, form saved successfully. I can see the saved values of hotel and parent in admin, but when I re-open the update form page, other fields returns but hotel and parent fields return blank. Any ideas?

Comment: ModelChoiceField is not meant to be used with a TextInput. Instead, why not use a [widget that is meant to work with choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget) ?

Comment: i need a input text type field. I am using select2 for autocomplete. But even i disable select2 .Fields are blank

Comment: why exactly are you excluding those two fields?

Comment: i am making them autocomplete for select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I handled it like below

views.py

```
class ProductUpdateView(BaseProductUpdateView):
    form_class = ProductForm
    slug_field = "id"

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super(ProductUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        kwargs['initial']['hotel'] = self.get_object().hotel.id if \
            self.get_object().hotel else None
        kwargs['initial']['parent'] = self.get_object().parent.id if \
            self.get_object().parent else None
        return kwargs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.hotel = form.cleaned_data["hotel"]
        form.instance.parent = form.cleaned_data["parent"]
        return super(ProductUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget = forms.TextInput

    def clean(self, value):
        value = super(AutoCompleteModelChoiceField, self).clean(value)
        return value


class ProductForm(BaseProductForm):
    hotel = AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(queryset=Hotel.objects.all())
    parent = AutoCompleteModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(),
                                          required=False)
```